# angular FullCalendar Cannot read property

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

premise I'm new and I still have a lot to learn.
I downloaded from git fullcalendar (https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-angular), after opening the project, after doing npm install and ng serve I get this error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of undefined
at Object.addParseSpanInfo
at AstTranslator.visitMethodCall 
at MethodCall.visit 
at AstTranslator.translate 
at Object.astToTypescript 
at TcbEventHandlerTranslator.TcbExpressionTranslator.translate 
at tcbEventHandlerExpression 
at tcbCreateEventHandler 
at TcbUnclaimedOutputsOp.execute 
at Scope.executeOp
```

do you have any suggestions on how to solve the problem?
thanks a lot to everyone

Comment: can you post the code here?

Comment: Have you tried the npm install after the download fullcalendar from git?

Comment: yes as it is written in the question I did npm install

Comment: the code is on the link :)

Comment: @BenTech I think you can check this link https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-example-projects/tree/master/angular. this will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
npm install --save @fullcalendar/angular @fullcalendar/daygrid
```

This is the new version of `fullcalendar`, the old one is deprecated.

For further reference: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular